# How to shutdown individual application (context) in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, contextpath

I deployed two applications appA & appB in tomcat.

So I see these in tomcat dir:

```
/tomcat/webapp/{appA,appB}
```

Is there a way to shutdown only one of the contexts without restarting tomcat ?
I tried removing the directory and `.war` file, but it seems not to trigger tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tomcat, deleting the war file should undeploy the application. Kindly take a look at the log files as they will reveal why the app did not get undeployed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Tomcat Manager and click on undeploy. I hope you have configured an access to the management part of Tomcat via the tomcat-user.xml. You need to give at least one user the role "manager-gui" to control via GUI.